# TextArea malfunctions and the app hangs - cn1

Tags: codenameone

I've a text area which often works but 1 in 10 time, it malfunctions. What happens is that the keypad overlaps the text area and then the text written is seen in other components above, then the app hangs. If the back btn is clicked it seems to work again but the issue is seen again and again

See the video [here](https://youtu.be/EFquPecL-MU)

**code:**

```
public TestDrive(Resources res) {
    super(new BorderLayout());
    getToolbar().setTitle("Test Drive");

    nameLabel = new Label("Name*: ");
    nameLabel.setUIID("small");
    nameData = new TextField();

    mailLabel = new Label("Email*: ");
    mailLabel.setUIID("small");
    mailData = new TextField();

    mobileLabel = new Label("Mobile No*: ");
    mobileLabel.setUIID("small");
    mobileData = new TextField();

    addressLabel = new Label("Address*: ");
    addressLabel.setUIID("small");
    addressData = new TextField();

    vehicleLabel = new TextArea("Current Vehicle: ");
    vehicleData = new TextField();

    interestedModelLabel = new TextArea("Model Intestested*: ");

    interestedModelData = new Picker();
    interestedModelData.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_STRINGS);
    interestedModelData.setSelectedString("Select the model");

    TextArea preferredDateLabel = new TextArea("Preferred Date: ");

    Picker preferredDateData = new Picker();
    preferredDateData.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_DATE);

    TextArea preferredTimeLabel = new TextArea("Preferred Time: ");
    Picker preferredTimeData = new Picker();
    preferredTimeData.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_TIME);

    TextArea preferredLocationLabel = new TextArea("Preferred Location: ");

    Picker preferredLocationData = new Picker();
    preferredLocationData.setType(Display.PICKER_TYPE_STRINGS);
    preferredLocationData.setTickerEnabled(false);
    preferredLocationData.setSelectedString("Select the dealer location");

    Label commentLabel = new Label("Comment*: ");
    TextArea commentData = new TextArea(); //problem occurs here
    commentData.setRows(4);
    commentData.setUIID("TextField");
    commentData.setScrollVisible(false);

    Button submitButton = new Button(" Submit ");

    TableLayout tl = new TableLayout(5, 2);
    Container testDriveContainer = new Container(tl);

    testDriveContainer.add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(35), nameLabel).add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(65), nameData)
            .add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(35), mailLabel).add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(65), mailData)
            .add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(35), mobileLabel).add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(65), mobileData)
            .add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(35), addressLabel).add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(65), addressData)
            .add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(35), FlowLayout.encloseCenterMiddle(vehicleLabel)).add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(65), vehicleData)
            .add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(35), FlowLayout.encloseCenterMiddle(interestedModelLabel)).add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(65), interestedModelData)
            .add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(35), FlowLayout.encloseCenterMiddle(preferredDateLabel)).add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(65), preferredDateData)
            .add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(35), FlowLayout.encloseCenterMiddle(preferredTimeLabel)).add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(65), preferredTimeData)
            .add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(35), FlowLayout.encloseCenterMiddle(preferredLocationLabel)).add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(65), preferredLocationData)
            .add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(35), commentLabel).add(tl.createConstraint().widthPercentage(65), commentData);

    Container mainContainer = BoxLayout.encloseY(testDriveContainer, FlowLayout.encloseCenter(submitButton));
    mainContainer.setScrollableY(true);
    add(BorderLayout.CENTER, mainContainer);

    revalidate();
}
```

Comment: Where is `commentData` added to the parent container hierarchy?

Comment: It is added to the testDriveContainer which is a table layout and this testDriveContainer is added to a mainContainer which is a boxlayout with scrollable y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this.  This issue has been fixed in Git https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/commit/7ba4c547b4464fa529e2378b4dd4c465cd290963.  The fix will be included in the next server update on Friday.